# In the implementation of my interface A I want to return an instance of type interface B

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, architecture, solid-principles

I've been trying to work this out for a couple of days now and I need a little push in the right direction.

**The issue:**

I'm trying to build a simple log-in system in my web-application. I'm trying to make it so that there's loose coupling between my classes. 
I built two interfaces;

```
public interface Authenticable {
    String getUsername();
    boolean changePassword(char[] password);
}
```

This interface will be implemented by classes that can be authenticated.

---

```
public interface Authenticator {
    Authenticable authenticate(String username, char[] password) throws AuthenticationException;
}
```

And this interface will be implemented by classes that can authenticate an Authenticable.

---

Currently I do not have a database or anything but I decided I want to be able to build a simple Authenticator first and later be able to swap it out for a different one (Which might use a database or a filesystem).

So the first implementation I made was:

```
public class HardcodedAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    @Override
    public Authenticable authenticate(String username, char[] password) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (username == "test" && password == new char[]{'t', 'e', 's', 't'}) {

        }
    }
}
```

This implementation simply checks if the username equals 'test' and the password equals 'test'.

If it does: Return an instance of Authenticable. 
If it doesn't: Throw an AuthenticationException.

---

However in my HardcodedAuthenticator I don't want to be limited to an implementation of the Authenticable (Atleast that's what I think would be best) but I still want to be able to return an instance of Authenticable..

**The question:**

*How does implementation Y of interface A return an instance of interface B?*

Thanks a lot in advance. 
Christian Adkin

Comment: Ur query is confusing.. Need a bit more clarifications

Comment: So you want different implementations of `Authenticable` to be possible? You can have a `setAuthenticable(Authenticable a)` which is then used by the class, or allow subclasses of `HardcodedAuthenticator` to override the default implementation. The strategy or factory method/abstract factory to achieve this kind of behavior.

Comment: Confused statement "However in my HardcodedAuthenticator I don't want to be limited to an implementation of the Authenticable (Atleast that's what I think would be best) but I still want to be able to return an instance of Authenticable..".

Comment: If I am understanding correctly change the method return type of method to object. or implement all the interface whose instance you like to return.

Comment: Till now I am not clear about your query but your "interface Authenticable " can always extend other interface and "HardcodedAuthenticator " can always implement other interfaces.  If "Authenticable " extend another interface "B"  tehn you can make return type of this method "authenticate" as "B"

Comment: @d.j.brown Yes that's what I want.

Comment: @DeepakAgrawal I want the return type to be of type Authenticable.

Comment: @smrutiranjan The Authenicator interfaces can authenticate Authenticable interfaces. I hope that somewhat clears is up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if I understand your problem correctly You dont want your implementation of Authenticator to have a dependency on any specific implementation of Authenticable you need to inject reference of type Authenticable to your Authenticator

```
        public interface Authenticator {
                  Authenticable authenticate(String username, char[] password,Authenticable authenticable) throws AuthenticationException;
       }
```

try to do some research about dependency injection, you will find many helpful articles if you still confused about it.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant with my question. This looks like a great way of solving my problem and I'll be doing research into dependency injection.